# Add additional .d.ts files with module declarations

Tags: typescript

Is there an option to include additional `.d.ts` files when using `tsc` with `declarations`?

My project is defined as following:

- `package.json` defines `"main": "build"` and `"typings": "./build/index.d.ts"`
- `tsconfig.json` defines `"declaration": true` and `"outDir": "build"`
- with those definitions and `src/index.ts`, `import X from 'mypackage'` works, and goes to `build/index.js`.

I also have `src/foo/index.ts` but I since don't want users of the package to `import foo from 'mypackage/build/foo'`, I added `foo.js` in the root, with

```
module.exports = require('./build/foo')
```

and now it's possible to `import foo from 'mypackage/foo'`

Problem is, that on consuming project, it errors

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'mypackage/foo'
```

I would like to add an additional `.d.ts` into the build folder when `tsc` runs; `build/foo.d.ts` that contains the declaration for `src/foo/index.ts`.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Since TypeScript is looking for a declaration file at `mypackage/foo`, creating `mypackage/build/foo.d.ts` will not help anything.  You'll need to either create `mypackage/foo.d.ts` containing something like:

```
import foo = require('./build/foo');
export = foo;
```

or do the redirection using a `mypackage/foo/package.json` file with a `main` field pointing to `../build/foo` (TypeScript will automatically add the `.d.ts` extension).